# Does same owner's prior application count as of filing or publication date?

Tags: prior-art, usa, non-obviousness

For 103/obviousness (but not obvious-type double patenting) reasons, does an application published by the same inventor/owner count as prior art against future applications of the inventor/owner based on **(a) the effective filing date** or **(b) publication date** of the earlier application?  Does it change from pre-AIA to post-AIA?  And are international applications treated differently?

For example, if I file an application on January 1 2015 which publishes on July 1 2017, can the examiner cite that application against me in a 103 rejection on an application filed June 1 2017 (i.e. citing the earlier app's effective filing date of Jan 1 2015) or not?

Based on my interpretation of 35 USC 102, it seems that one's own prior applications are treated differently (count as prior art as of pub date) relative to others' prior-filed applications (count as prior art as of EFD).

A pre-AIA [Patently-O article](https://patentlyo.com/patent/2012/09/continuations-in-part-and-priority-claims.html) makes the following statement (emphasis mine) in regards to CIP applications, which neither contradicts nor explicitly confirms my interpretation:

> Thus, for the claims with new matter *any patent issued or document published more than one-year before* the CIP filing date would count as prior art under 35 U.S.C. 102(b).

Comment: This answer seems to confirm my interpretation: https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/4962/18769

Answer (score 1):

1. For the case of post-AIA US (i.e. applications filed on/after Mar 16, 2013), same inventor's prior application is not prior art until 1 year after publication date.
2. Pre-AIA, not sure?
3. In other jurisdictions, same inventor's prior application generally counts as prior art for novelty purposes as of date of filing (an in-built way to avoid double-patenting), but not for obviousness until publication (no 1-year grace period like the US).

See [here](http://info.henrypatentfirm.com/blog/prior-art-under-aia) and [here](http://aboutiplaw.com/noteworthy/patent-noteworthy/1425/).

A further question would be, do common assignees get the same benefit of common inventors?